# деплой проекта с github/bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Народ, поделитесь опытом или советами как лучше деплоить проетк с хостингов проектов github и/или bitbucket?
Какие есть готовые решения и/или способы самостоятельного решения?

Comment: Не уловил суть проблемы,  можно поподробней!?

Comment: @KirillStoianov хочу разобраться с вопросом - как выкладывать на боевой сервер проект разрабатываемый на github или bitbucket

Answer (score 1):

Самостоятельное решение основано на так называемых [hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Git). В случае, если центральный репозиторий размещён на вашем сервере, при push'е git вызывает ваш скрипт, который берёт последнюю версию кода и развёртывает его.

С GitHub и bitbucket этот номер не пройдёт — вы не можете разметить свои скрипты на их серверах. Вместо этого вы используете [web hooks](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/) — при push'е GitHub обращается по указанному вами URL, где вы размещаете скрипт развёртывания.

Скрипт развёртывания в простейшем случае это загрузка последней версии кода из репозитория и копирование его в каталог хостинг, или выкладывание на FTP. В более сложных случаях может потребоваться запуск утилитит (например, минификаторов js и css) и даже полноценная предварительная сборка проекта с помощью [make](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make), [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) или [MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd393574.aspx).

Таким образом у вас, помимо репозиториев GitHub и хостинга, должен быть настроен сервер сборки (build server). Для небольших проектов его можно размещать там же, где и хостинг. В случае обновления кода в центральном репозитории, GitHub «вызывает» посредством web-запроса скрипт, размещённый на build-сервере, который собирает проект, прогоняет тесты и копирует сборку на хостинг.

Готовые решения основаны на том же самом принципе, но вместо ручного написания скриптов, вы используете то, что уже подготовили для вас разработчики. Вы берёте, например, [CruiseControl](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl) (есть в версиях для Java, .NET, Ruby и т.д.) устанавливаете его на своём build-сервере, и настраиваете.

Многие проблемы там решены прямо из коробки, в частности, CruiseControl может оповещать вас по e-mail о неудачных сборках и готовить отчёты.

Лично я, работая под .NET, использую Build Server от Microsoft, входящий в [Visual Studio Online](http://visualstudio.com). Для небольших команд до 5-ти человек, и небольших сборок это даже бесплатно. Вам же надо искать решение, подходящее под вашу платформу.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ! а какие вы можете назвать хорошие готовые решения?

Comment: Я в статье дописал ответ. Лично я использую Visual Studio Online, но я пишу под .NET, поэтому так. До этого использовал CruiseControl, для моих персональных нужд его хватало. У Вас какая платформа?

Comment: работаю на php в netBeans

Comment: Ну, PHP не требует компиляции, так что в простейшем случае можете действительно разместить скрипт прямо на хостинге, чтобы загружал с GitHub последнюю версию кода и копировал в папку хостинга. К сожалению, посоветовать конкретные инструменты не могу, поскольку очень давно не PHP не работаю. Google подсказывает https://www.phptesting.org/ и http://sismo.sensiolabs.org/